# Require a module as if its module is the module you are requiring it from

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like require a module and somehow pass in the current module, or something like that, such that the module being required has the properties of the module requiring it.

For example if I have a file I'm requiring:

```
(function(global) {
  console.log(this.exists);
}(this));
```

And am requiring it like so:

```
this.exists = "I exist.";
var myFile = require("my-file"); // Somehow make require pass in 'this'.
```

The file being required should be able to see `this.exists` since I've passed `this` into the `require` function somehow. I'm not sure if this is possible. I would think you would need to fiddle with the different `module` objects.

The one constraint of this is that the module being required can't have any `nodejs` specific things, like code to export it on the module. It has to stay the same as the way I've written it.

**Edit:**

Turns out there is no way to do this exactly the way I want to. There have been some awesome suggestions on how to do this in other ways, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do something similar to this once... best way I figured out was through a level of indirection.

**Part1:**

```
define(function() {
    "use strict";

    function init() {
        console.log("this = " + this);
    }

    return init;
});
```

**Part2:**

```
var myFileInit = require("my-file");
var myFile = myFileInit.init.call(this);
```

**Edit: Another possibility**

Create a wrapper for the original module:

```
// my-file-wrapper
define(["my-file"], function(myFunc) {
    "use strict";

    function init() {
        myFunc.call(this);
    }

    return init;
});

// Elsewhere
var myFileWrapper = require("my-file-wrapper");
var myFile = myFileInit.init.call(this);
```

Comment: I'd like to not have to modify the module being required if at all possible. This is a good solution if I have to relax my constraints a bit though.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Would there be a way of doing this without a file wrapper and an init method? If that's not possible then that would answer my main question. Your solution gives me an alternative if it's not possible.

Comment: If there is such a way, I haven't found it.

Comment: Okay, that's what I suspected. I'm going to take this as an answer that it's not possible then and elect to use your method :-). Thanks!